# Working out Normalised Floating Points

Tags: math, binary, floating, hex

From the following options, expressed in hexadecimal notation, select the answer which is a normalised floating point number: Pick 1 answer

I know the answer is one but I forgot how to work out this question, can anyone assist?

1.80800000

2.ff800000

3.80080000

4.FFF8FFFF

Answer (score 1):

Normalized values are numbers where the exponent part is between 0x01 and 0xFE. Other exponents have special meanings. The first option has an exponent part of 0x01, the second and fourth options have 0xFF and the third option has 0x00.